# Examples of using Eunit to test clustered application

Tags: unit-testing, erlang, distributed, eunit

I find the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/eunit/chapter.html) on Eunit lacking, with regards to how to test a multi-node application. I found this [example](https://github.com/richcarl/eunit/blob/master/examples/eunit_examples.erl), but sadly when I run:

```
cluster_test_() ->  
    {node, foo,
     fun (Node) ->
        [?_assertEqual(pong, net_adm:ping(Node))]
     end
    }.
```

I get:

```
undefined
*** context setup failed ***
** in function slave:start/5 (slave.erl, line 197)
**exit:not_alive
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

As a sidenote, I also looked at gproc's distributed test [here](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/test/gproc_dist_tests.erl), but it's [manually starting](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/blob/master/test/gproc_dist_tests.erl#L465-L468) a number of slave nodes rather than using the built-in Eunit functionality.

Can someone give me some examples of how to use use the `node` test fixture?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[Common Test](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/basics_chapter.html) was written especially for testing bigger systems.

Other that official documentation you can find very good introduction to theme [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests).  And chapter evens ends with [small snippet](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests#integrating-eunit) howto integrate existing eunit tests into Common Test.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to do that with Eunit, will try common test instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I never got the slave node functionality to work properly, so it shouldn't be a documented feature. I guess it ended up in the docs while I still thought it was working. I'll probably have to fix the docs.

Comment: Ha, premature feature documentation, something I've been guilty of a few times too :-P

Answer (score 0):

If you are going with multi-node tests and eunit keep in mind then eunit ifdefs in modules will change it's checksums, and if you say have one module compiled with ifdef eunit and another is not you will have errors if try to call remote functions.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you run your master node with disabled distribution. Enable it with `-sname` key (I assume, your example code is located in module `node_test`):

```
> erl -sname master
(master@hostname)1> c(node_test).
> node_test:test().
```

But it is not all. To run this code in new versions of erlang, you should make a little changes:

```
cluster_test_() ->  
    {node, foo,
     fun ({Node, StopNet}) ->
        ?debugFmt("Node ~p", [Node]),
        ?debugFmt("StopNet ~p", [StopNet]),
        [?_assertEqual(pong, net_adm:ping(Node))]
     end
    }.
```

Note, function argument now contains not node name, but tuple with two elements. First element is remote node name, second - is boolean flag which always false (at least for now). For more detail refer to [eunit sources](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/eunit/src/eunit_data.erl#L295)